# Difficulty formatting tf.example for making requests to Tensorflow serving

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have two broad questions regarding the best way to make requests to TensorFlow Serving:

1. When stability is much more of a concern than throughput is there any benefit to using gRPC over REST, which is both easier to interact with and easier to encode data inputs?
2. When using gRPC, what is the recommended way of creating tf.examples from a python client. We have seen this done overlaying it with a beam schema and also by tediously recursing through JSON and constructing individual objects along the way. None of these methods seem robust, efficient or easy for such an important component of serving.

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

As to your second question: I'm not an expert myself, but this is how I have done it in the past.

Supposed that you have data for multiple inputs that live in a `request_dict` which maps tensor names to numpy arrays, you can populate a request object as follows:

```
from tensorflow_serving.apis import predict_pb2
from tensorflow.contrib.util import make_tensor_proto    

request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
request.model_spec.name = 'tf_serving'
request.model_spec.signature_name = 
tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY 

for k, v in request_dict.items(): # keys are tensor names, values are np arrays
    request.inputs[k].CopyFrom(make_tensor_proto(v, shape=v.shape))
```

I agree that this is tedious and that documentation on this part is lacking for python users. Using REST is indeed easier, but I cannot comment on your first question about gRPC vs REST.